# Jquery disable/enable on key press

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to add a small jquery feature onto a form but can't seem to get it running right:

```
$("#progress-reg").keypress(function(event){
       var n = $('#progress-reg').length;
       $('#progress-next').prop("disabled", (n < 1) ? true : false);
});
```

The idea being if a user starts typing into `#progress-reg` it will enable the `#progress-next` button (which works fine), but if the user deletes the content of #progress-reg I would like it so the button reverts to being disabled but the above code does not seem to do this.

I did have a search on here before posting but can't see anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should check the length of the value in the input, not the input itself.
2. You should bind `keyup` instead of `keypress`.

```js
$("#progress-reg").on("keyup", function(){
    var n = this.value.length;
    $("#progress-next").prop("disabled", n < 1 ? true : false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="progress-reg" /><button id="progress-next" disabled>Next</button>
```

Comment: Well i do recommend that you test if its not already disabled but its not a must

Answer (score 1):

use remove prop disabled if n< 1
https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/

```
$("#progress-reg").keyup(function(event){
       var n = $(this).val().length;
       if (n < 1) $('#progress-next').removeProp("disabled");
       else if ($('#progress-next').prop("disabled") == false) $('#progress-next').prop("disabled",true);

});
```

Comment: Thanks Sebo, I did try this too but used the shorter code in the end

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.on('input',..` event, it work with copy/paste. Use the `val()` methode to get the content and then add or remove the `disabled` attribute to the button.

```js
$('#progress-next').prop("disabled", true)
// work with copy paste
$("#progress-reg").on('input',function(event){
       var n = $(this).val().length;
        $('#progress-next').prop("disabled", n < 1)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="progress-reg">
<button id="progress-next">OK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length of the `value` property

```
$("#progress-reg").keypress(function(event){
       $('#progress-next').prop("disabled", this.value.length == 0);
});
```

Also I reworked your code a bit to be shorter.